How to push execution js code in middle of it's execution with it's memory state
let's say there is a Node js Server for prime number, it serves to web page one for user input and the other for result
When 1st user demands the nth prime number on the first page, prime number calculation is written in the async-await pattern. Still, the code is executed on the main thread, so while prime number execution is ongoing, that time 2nd user demands the first web page.
Is there a way to push the prime number function with its memory state, serve the page to the second user and then resume the function

Consider using worker_threads in a worker pool to do the CPU heavy prime number crunching. This will leave the main event loop free to respond to web requests. Alternatively, you could use something like await new Promise(resolve => setImmediate(resolve)) in between prime number calculation iterations - this will slow it down a lot but will essentially spread out the calculations to multiple event loop iterations so that the web server can handle requests during that time.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
